# Java - Using parallel arrays to find common frequent number/s

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array and have already sorted it. I want to be able to find which numbers repeat. Following that, I want to be able to count how many times these numbers repeat. For example in a list [1,2,3,3,4,4] 3 and 4 repeats and they both repeats twice. My following code is able to find which numbers repeats but unable to get my mind around on how to count the number of times they each repeat. And I am using ArrayList. Trying to skip that and keep everything to purely just arrays excluding hashmap too. Appreciate any help. Tnks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {          
        int[] num = {1,2,3,3,4,4}; 

        for(int x : num){
            System.out.print(x + " ");  
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + freq(num));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> freq(int[] num){    
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int x=0; x < num.length-1; x++){
            if(num[x] == num[x+1]){
                if(!list.contains(num[x])){  
                    list.add(num[x]); 
                }
            } 
        }           
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since your array is sorted,you could use another array where each index corresponds to the amount of hits for this number:

```
int[] count = new int[num[num.length - 1]];
```

Then you could increment the index of this counter for each match:

```
count[num[x] - 1] = count[num[x] - 1] + 1;
```

This would however not compact your representation, just bring it to another form. Since you do not know the result lenght before the computation, a more compact representation without lists or even better maps is however not possible since the size of an array must be known at creation. This solution will only work with numbers bigger than 0. For other ranges, you have to adjust the offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {          
      int[] num = {1,2,3,3,4,4}; 

      for(int x : num){
        System.out.print(x + " ");  
      }

      System.out.println("\n" + freq(num));
    }

    static class ValueCountPair {
        public ValueCountPair( final int val )
        {
            value = val;
            count = 2;      
        }
        public int value;
        public int count;

        public String toString() {
            return "[" + value + ": " + count + "]";
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<ValueCountPair> freq(final int[] num){
        ArrayList<ValueCountPair> list = new ArrayList<ValueCountPair>();

        ValueCountPair last = null;
        for(int x=0; x < num.length-1; x++){
            if(num[x] == num[x+1]){
                if ( last == null || last.value != num[x+1] )
                    list.add( last = new ValueCountPair( num[x+1] ) );
                else
                    ++last.count;
            } 
        }           
        return list;
    }
}
```